# adb cannot accurately read IMEI 1 and 2

Tags: android, adb, imei, oppo

there are two OPPO phones, using adb cannot accurately read IMEI 1 and 2, but only MEID. How can I read IMEI?

Android version 11 Model PEAM00 and PEMM20

Tried the following command, but it doesn't work, only MEID is returned.

adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1

adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 2

Answer (score 0):

Found in a different StackOverflow thread that I can't find now:

```
adb shell "service call iphonesubinfo 1 | cut -c 52-66 | tr -d '.[:space:]'"
```

This is working on Android 11. If it's not working straight from CMD then type

```
adb shell
```

and then the rest of the command (service call ...)

Comment: thank,but it return MEID.It does not return IMEI

Comment: I tested this on over 500 Samsung Galaxy S20FE phones, running Android 11, returned IMEI in all of them

Comment: I have also tried other Android 11 phones, which can also work, but these two don't work。

Comment: Test other mobile phones of the same model and find that they can read normally，It can be concluded that it is a mobile phone problem. Why is this happening

Answer (score 0):

The script created by me extract all device information (including all IMEI numbers) and it theoretically works on all devices.

It is here: https://github.com/micro5k/microg-unofficial-installer/blob/main/utils/device-info.sh

If it doesn't work on a device that you have you can create a ticket at the same repository.